# Дано случайное число, необходимо преобразовать данное число в строку из символов алфавита

Tags: php, строки

в общем нужно написать функцию,  чтобы сначала подбирался соответствующий символ из английского алфавита под двузначный номер, если такое возможно, иначе под однозначный номер

Например: 132722 = 13(n) - 2(c) - 7(h) - 22(w) = nchw

Вот что я смог сделать

1. Разобрать число на составляющие по условию, т.е разделить те числа которые больше 25

```
<?php

$num = 132722;
$search = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

for ($j = 0; $j < mb_strlen($num); $j+=2) {

    $test = mb_substr($num, $j, 2);

    if ($test > 25) {
        $test =  mb_substr($num, $j, 1);
        $j-=1;
    }

    echo $test . " "; // 13 2 7 22

}
```

2. Получить порядковый номер числа в алфавите для последующего сравнения

```
<?php

for ($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen($search); $i++) {
    $symbol = mb_substr($search, $i, 1);

    $pos = mb_strpos($search, $symbol);
     echo $symbol . " = " . $pos . " " . $br ;

    

}
```

Вопрос в том как мне можно объеденить эти догадки в одну функцию и сравнивать каждый числитель с порядковым номером алфавита и соответственно выводить результат.

Comment: `echo $search[$test] . " "; //n c h w `

Answer (score 0):

```
function foo(int $number, string $alphabet): string {
    $numberString = (string)$number;
    $numberLength = strlen($number);
    $alphabetLength = strlen($alphabet);
    $index = 0;
    $result = '';
    
    do {
        for ($i = 2; $i > 0; $i--) {
            $part = substr($numberString, $index, $i);
            $partNumber = (int)$part;
            
            if ($partNumber >= 0 && $partNumber < $alphabetLength) {
                $result .= $alphabet[$partNumber];
                $index += $i;
                break;
            }
        }
    } while ($index < $numberLength);
    
    return $result;
}
```